# Set sequential numbers to columns of group of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table looking like this:

```
*  user_id   index
1   1      (null)
2   2      (null)
3   2      (null)
4   2      (null)
5   3      (null)
6   3      (null)
```

I need to set the index column so that there are sequential numbers for every users:

```
*  user_id   index
1   1      1
2   2      1
3   2      2
4   2      3
5   3      1
6   3      2
```

I tried something like this

```
create sequence my_seq;
UPDATE my_table SET index=my_seq.nextval WHERE USER_ID=3;
```

but clearly I can't do this for each ID. Is there a way to do this for all the records?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the expected result if another row with user_id = 2 is added? Or one of them is removed?

Comment: I don't need to handle that now, the only thing I need is to update the existing data.

Comment: I'd consider a view instead, with data which is consistent even after insert/delete operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `MERGE` statement with the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```
MERGE INTO my_table dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID rid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id
                             ORDER BY /*Your order condition*/ ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   my_table
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.rid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET "index" = src.rn WHERE "index" IS NULL;
```

Comment: It always makes me squirm that the best answer to an UPDATE requirement for Oracle is usually to use MERGE instead ;)